# Email only specific values in a for loop

Tags: python

This is my first time using Python to call an `API`, so please bear with me.

I was able to grab from the list of everything, but I only want to store the users that are disabled in a variable and then send the variable as an email.

The entire list is as follows:

```
username, address, etc, ..., enabled
username1, address, etc, ..., disabled
username2, address, etc, ..., enabled
username3, address, etc, ..., disabled
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
users = admin_api.get_users()

for user in users:
       #some code that only adds username and status to a variable if status = disabled 

#if variable has a value, send email, if not, do not send email. 
if variable is None:

me= "from@123.com"
you = "to@123.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Users that are disabled"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Here are the list of disabled users<br>
     $VARIABLE  
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part)
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp@123.com')
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Output:
Email shows only users that are disabled:
username1 account is disabled
username3 account is disabled

Thanks

Comment: How do you tell if a user is disabled?

Comment: yep, you should filter the users that are disabled the object should have a property to know its state.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but when I call Users, it will give me a list of all users along with the other attributes.  I only want to list users who's attribute is disabled.

Comment: @BobWhite , agreed but i dont know the python commands to filter it.

Comment: @kahtools, can you post a sample of the actual string returned by the `API`? It looks like a `CSV` but I just to want to be sure.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it a substitute for guides, tutorials, and documentation. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming below that `users` is a list of dictionaries like this:

```
{"username": "username1", "address": "address1", ..., "status": "disabled"}
```

Adjust the syntax if it's something else, like class instances.

Then use a list comprehension and then join the results.

```
disabled_users = "<br>".join([user['username'] + ' is disabled' for user in users if user['status'] == 'disabled'])
```

And in the HTML you can then substitute the variable

```
html = f"""
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Here are the list of disabled users<br>
     {disabled_users} 
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get a SyntaxError: Invalid syntax on when

Comment: @kahoots, replace `when` with `if`.